# How to add Q lookups with the get_queryset in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, filtering, query-string

I have written some filtering code in get_queryset function. Also I have a separate search filter api which searches based on the string provided in the query parameter search. Now what I want is add the search query into the former filtering logic so that user can search only in the filtered results and not from the whole database again.

My model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   
    WARRANTY = (
        ('no_warranty', 'No Warranty',),
        ('local_seller_warranty', 'Local Seller Warranty',),
        ('brand_warranty', 'Brand Warranty',),
    )
    
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    mini_category = models.ForeignKey(Minicategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?

    /.........other codes.........../
```

My filtering view:

```
class ProductAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()    
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        brand = self.request.GET.get('brand', None)
        sub_category = self.request.GET.get("sub_category", None)
        warranty = self.request.GET.get("warranty", None)
        if brand is not None:
            
            brand_values = brand.split(",")
            if sub_category is not None:
                
                sub_category_values = sub_category.split(",")
                if warranty is not None:
                    
                    warranty_values = warranty.split(",")
                    return Product.objects.filter(brand__name__in=brand_values,
                                                  sub_category__name__in=sub_category_values,
                                                  warranty__in=warranty_values)
         /..........other codes........../
```

My url to call this

```
localhost/api/products?brand=Samsung,Lg&warranty=no_warranty
```

Q lookup search view:

```
from django.db.models import Q
class PrdouctSearchAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qur = self.request.query_params.get('search')
        item = Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name__icontains=qur) |
                                          Q(brand__name__icontains=qur) |
                                          Q(description__icontains=qur) |
                                          Q(collection__name__icontains=qur) |
                                          Q(name__icontains=qur) |
                                          Q(variants__color__icontains=qur)).distinct()

        return item
```

url to perform this view:

```
localhost/api/productsearch?search=frontload
```

Now what I want is to combine the two apis like `localhost/api/products?brand=Samsung` I need to display only Samsung brands machines. Now when I add search=frontload in the same api `localhost/api/products?brand=Samsung&search=frontload` like I need to display samsung machines with frontload only. how to achieve it??

Comment: Do you only need to filter on `brand` or do you need a general solution that will allow filtering on other fields as well? If you need a general solution, I suggest using `django-filter`. It will do all of this for you with very little code on your part.

Comment: but django-filter doesnt allow me to query on multiple parameters at the same time. Just like api/products?name=LG,samsung,sony&type=front,back. Thats why I have used custom code with split)(',') in get queryset.

Comment: You didn't include that as a requirement in your question.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you can implement a `FilterSet` using `django-filter` which allows multiple values for a single key. I would start by defining a filter using the `__in` suffix.

Comment: Can you provide me some code snippets to show how it can be done>>

Comment: for eg will `filterset_fields = [brand__in]` will allow me to split the commas in between brand name like lg,snoy??

Answer (score 0):

You can also have different combination with Pipe(|) and, And(&) like this:

```
super(YourClass, self).get_queryset.filter(Q(industry__icontains=industry) | Q(size_of_company__icontains=size_of_comapany) & Q(liquidity__icontains=liquidity))
```